# How to determine if receivedTurnEventFor is an Invite?

Tags: swift, game-center

After reading various questions, I've understood that Invites to GKTurnBasedMatches are not sent until the invited user's turn comes. And that invite is handled through the " func player(_ player: GKPlayer, 
receivedTurnEventFor match" class.

But I'm not sure how to handle an invite at this point? I'd like to offer the user the opportunity to Accept/Decline an invite. Is this where I should write code to the effect of:

if Received Turn Event == Invite { Ask To Decline/Accept }

If so, how do I do that? How do I determine if there was an invite, and how do I accept/decline that invite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've solved this by using this code:

```
  if match.currentParticipant?.status == .invited {
           print("Was invited")
// Present option to act on invite
}
```